# I worked under master branch and then switch to development on my local machine, would it affects my master branch

Tags: git, github, git-branch

I cloned the repository from master branch and start working on master branch on my local machine, after working i created and switched to development branch, now is it safe to push under development brach, because i only want to push to development branch only.

I don't want any changes in my master branch, so should simply push or there is any other procedure.

Kindly help!

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing your development branch has all the commits you want to push. You should be fine to checkout the development branch and push to remote. NOTE: I've assumed your development is called `dev` in my example below.

1. Check out the development branch via `git checkout dev`
2. Push to remote and simultaneously set upstream of the branch using `git push -u origin dev`.

You can undo the changes you've made in your local master branch by doing the following:

1. Check out the master branch with `git checkout master`.
2. Reset master back to origin with `git reset --hard origin/master`